# Resharper inserts wrong snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm evaluating ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.1 with Visual Studio Po 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2 and have problems with some snippets.

E.g. Ctrl+k,s surround with #region snippet that worked ok without ReSharper, now inserts C++ regions even though it is in a C# file.

Does anybody know, why ReSharper inserts this snippet as C++ into my C# files?

TIA
Michael

Answer (score 0):

That's a VS bug.

VS 2015 mixes up snippet languages when the MEF cache is (re-)built. It could be the very first start of VS or a first start after a new VS extension installation.

Restarting VS fixes the issue.

Comment: No, restarting VS doesn't fix this.

Comment: You are right. We (ReSharper team) reported this issue to Microsoft, hopefully Visual Studio will fix it soon.